# ckfinder 2.6.x does not remember last folder

Tags: ckfinder

I downloaded trial version of the ckfinder and i noticed that it does not remember the last folder from previous use. I believe it should remember right since it has a config option. Also tried with different browsers like Chrome, Edge, Opera and set `config.rememberLastFolder = true` to be sure but still same, it always stars from `File` folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I figured out where the bug is!
First of all you need to open the file: `ckfinder.js`. The source code in this file is minified, so you need to "Reformat" it `(Ctrl + Alt + L in PhpStorm)` and then go to line **1070**. You will see a hardcoded cookie expiration date on this line. The problem is that this date is in the past, that's why cookies with CKFinder settings not saving in browser at all! I don't know why they put a hardcoded date, but all you need to do is change this date to something bigger, for example you can set: `expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2038 01:00:00 UTC`. It will solve the issue.

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdtAg.png)

Comment: Thanks, this answer really saved us, the original expire setting was: `expires=Thu, 6 Oct 2016 01:00:00 UTC; path=/`

Comment: Thank you. It's worked for me! :)